# Windows 7 takes very long time to log in

Tags: windows-7

I have been working on another computer that doesn't have a screen, a mouse or a keyboard. So I connected these things from another computer. When I was done working on the computer I connected the screen back and started it. The system was booting up correctly but since the mouse and the keyboard was connected to the other computer I couldn't do anything. So I connected the mouse and the keyboard but they didn't work. The cursor wasn't moving. So I powered off the computer using the powerbutton on the computer.

When starting the computer again I was stuck on the Welcome screen. So I turned the computer off again and tried to start the computer in safe mode, but also in safe mode I was stuck on welcome screen so I turned it off again. Now I tried booting in safe mode with console. I come to the welcome screen again and again I was stuck there. But now I leaved it on. After about 10 minutes a console was showing. I entered msconfig and pressed Enter. The msconfig window opened. I unchecked every startup program and then rebooted. Now I started windows normally. I was stuck on welcome screen again. I waited and after 10 minutes windows started. I launched the windows task manager. Everything worked fine. But when trying to launch other programs the system freezed.

What should I do? 
Reinstalling Windows 7 is not an option.

Comment: This indicates a problem with the HDD.

Comment: @Ramhound But why did it work normal the first time when mouse and keyboard wasn't connected?

Comment: Your system freezing is an indication your hdd is failing

Comment: @Ramhound And how do I prevent that.

Comment: Your replace it?

Comment: capture a boot trace of the slow boot: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. A window appeared under the boot named System reparation or something. I have been there many times before since the problem occured. The only difference now was that it asked me if I allowed it to make changes in the system. (It wouldn't affect personal data). I clicked Tes and it worked twenty minutes and then it was fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is by HDD you can check if your drives are not fragmented i recommend smart defragller to defrag your drives.

If above method not works try
Run command prompt as an admin type sfc /scannow then enter it will scan entire system root for problems that hanging down the system wait for process fully completed.
Then open run by win+R type msconfig.exe hit enter switch to startup tab and disable  the unused programs identify yourself.

Comment: Avoid adding any signature/contact on your post since it's irrelevant and not adding any quality. Worse, you might be assumed as attempting to spam.

Comment: File fragmentation wouldn't explain these symptoms, even if it was severe.  Defragmenting isn't entirely risk free and generally isn't needed unless fragmentation is severe, so that recommendation might not be a great one.  The msconfig recommendation is good, but the question states that it was already tried and didn't fix it.  Your sfc recommendation is probably a good next step.

Comment: Defragmentation isn't harmfull it would not remove any file from your system i also used it and my all files are present.

Comment: Removing files isn't the issue.  Things can get corrupted if anything interrupts the process.  While the risk might be low, there is little benefit to doing it unless there is extreme fragmentation.